# Help understanding formula $score(K) = \sum_{i,j} | d_{ij} - e_{ij} |$

Tags: matrices

I am trying to write some code to perform an equation based on the formula below, however I am having a hard time understanding mathematic syntax.

The formula is as follows:

$$
score(K) = \sum_{i,j}  | d_{ij} - e_{ij} | {}
$$

I know that $d$ and $e$ are matrices(I have those already) and I know that $score(K)$ is what im trying to calculate, what I dont understand from the formula above is what I actually *do* with my two matrices in order to get the "score".

(Bonus points for recognising the formula, and explaining in plain english what it's actually doing)

Comment: It can be understood as the sum of the absolute values of every element of the matrix $K=D-E$

Comment: @cjferes - can you expand that into an answer... sorry Im a bit of a math layman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula
$$\operatorname{score}(K)=\sum_{i,j}|d_{ij}-e_{ij}|$$

can be understood as follows:

1. $d_{ij}$ is the element of the $i$-th row and $j$-th column of matrix $D$. The same goes for $e_{ij}$, the elements of matrix $E$.
2. Let $K=D-E$. So, every element of matrix $K$, namely $k_{ij}$, is the substraction $d_{ij}-e_{ij}$.
3. Take absolute value, and then sum every result.

This is the same as summing up all absolute values of the elements of $K$, the substraction of $D-E$.

Also, as a side note, observe that 
$$\sum_{i,j}$$
is an abbreviation of 
$$\sum_i\sum_j$$

Comment: Thank you. I think I got it from your comment, but this makes it totally clear.

Comment: Do you need pseudo-code for implementation too?

Comment: No, thats quite alright. [Code I can do](http://stackoverflow.com/users/219661/jamiec) - its maths notation I'm new to. it was the vertical pipes that I mainly didn't understand - `Math.Abs` in my world.